# Fraudulent behavior

Tags: support, voting-fraud

I have a little trouble and am sorry to ask that here. Another user may apparently have five duplicates fake accounts.

I think evidence are there; I don't judge. Here are the facts about his questionable reputation on Stack Overflow.

Anyway, he targeted me by trying to steal a question's bounty from my answer by downvoting me and upvoting his answer...

I flagged his answer one day ago and still don't have an answer... I left this question as a last resort; I did not really want to go public... I also asked moderators about it on the chat, but still no answer. I know the moderators don't answer quickly; it's not a problem at all. I post here, because the bounty was ending in 10 min and I don't want to cheat.

Question: Removed for privacy

User: Removed for privacy

**Facts:**

Fact 1: It took me more than 3 hours to set up a similar environment, to answer the question, test the code, etc.

Fact 2: His answer is not compilable (and not correct, tested)

Fact 3: His answer does not match the OP's setup at all. It's completely different code, COPY PASTED from [I made soap request with the help of ksoap2 but no response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977151/i-made-soap-request-with-the-help-of-ksoap2-but-no-response) after a small makeup.

Fact 4: I waited two days to get two upvotes and he got five successive upvotes just after posting his answer.

Fact 5: In his reputation stack he has some time not spaced upvote just after answering like on this question and on May 13 (4 upvote in 5 min) and so on.

Fact 6: The OP is not responsible; he is offline and was connected almost two days ago

Fact 7: It's a specific problem not easy to setup, and the OP did not upvote his answer because he has been off-line for two days. (I don't know if the OP upvoted my answer).

Fact 8: I did get three upvotes, because I posted my question here (regardless of the two upvotes that I had).

Fact 9: The OP has been absent for two days.

Fact 10: I get the half the bounty because the OP is absent and because I get three upvotes from here after asking my question.

Fact 11: if he did not post, his copy pasted answer and upvoted it, I would also get the bounty

I did not know about the fact that moderators could roll back bounty points; it's why I asked here in a hurry...

I don't have direct proofs because I don't have moderator's access, but it's a conjunction of things that let me think he cheated (and personally I am convinced). I don't want to cheat; I play it fair, and I could create other account or just ask other friend to upvote me, but I don't want to go on that road...

If it was a simple question it would not matter; I don't care, or if his answer was legitimate it would not matter either... But I took a very long time to write that answer, test the code, etc., waited two days to get two upvotes...

And then he come with a copy past answer upvoted in 5 minutes... It's not fair at all... I don't believe in fortuity. I don't care if I get a moderator taking back reputation from me. I know my value, and at least the OP will be helped. I just don't want to be cheated by another user regarding the effort I put on my answer.

Comment: "He came with a fancy answer" -- is the answer better than yours? Why do you think the six up votes on their answer are fraudulent?

Comment: 1. the op did not upvote him and it's a very specific code (not connected) 
2. His code is general, could be done in 2 min 
3. in 2 or 3 days i got 2 vote by visitors and his answer get 6 votes in 10 min ???

Comment: By that logic, you yourself have employed three fraudulant accounts to uproot your answer. Four if you consider that had the OP uprooted it, they probably would have accepted & awarded the bounty as well.

Comment: @intika as you reported you should wait for moderators response. But I am also confused getting that much upvote in short time.

Comment: i don't want to cheat i play it fair, i could create other account but don't want to go on that road... if it was a simple question it does not matter i don't care, or if his answer was legit it does a matter as well... but i took a very longtime to write that answer test the code etc. waited 2 days to get 2 upvotes... and then he come with a fancy answer upvoted in 5 min it's not fair at all

Comment: Your answer now has more upvotes than theirs. How do you explain that, if you didn't cheat?

Comment: @TZHX, the newer upvotes have all been cast after this meta-question was posted. You may consider the Meta effect as "cheating", but it's arguably more complicated to rely on it than to spawn a couple of socks.

Comment: @Fred My point was, the user is so insistent that there's no way anyone but the OP could consider these answers worth an upvote and based on that is sure the other user engaged in vote fraud. I'm simply applying their own logic to them -- to show how ridiculous it can be.

Comment: i did all the possible before posting here i know what it mean to accuse someone.

Comment: :) I also thinking that intika getting new up-votes for this meta post.Btw I am not upvoter as I don't understand the answer.

Comment: @TZHX I upvoted him. That answer of that other guy seems like a simple copy and paste, and that addition seems irrelevant..

Comment: @TZHX, ah, I completely missed that. Probably too subtle for me on a Sunday ;)

Comment: So you just assume that anyone who gets lots of upvotes cheats? Based on this, Jon Skeet should get a lifetime suspension.

Comment: @ShadowWizard i never told that it's a conjunction of things that let me think he cheated 
1 - Wrong non compilable answer ... 2 - Upvotes (5) in short period of time on a wrong answer while i waited 2 days to get 2 votes ... 3 - Specific problem to op code, the answer does not match the op code at all ... 4 - the op did not upvote his answer (offline)

Comment: @intika how do you know the OP upvoted *your* answer?

Comment: @TZHX i don't know if the op upvoted mine or not what i know is the op was offline when the other user get all his upvote

Comment: why is that relevant?

Comment: @TZHX it's a specific problem, i spend almost 1h reproducing the environment of the question before even start answering

Comment: it seems that you saw you were going to lose the auto awarded bounty and so came to meta with baseless accusations, resulting in you getting it.

Comment: @TZHX it seems you are right.OP asked this question because he may be losing auto bounty.But it also suspicious if someone got upvotes on wrong answer(claimed by OP). I hope you will check that code too.

Comment: i updated my question to be more clear and because i wrote it in a hurry

Comment: @Shaiful I don't care enough to check the code. But I doubt anyone who voted on the answers did, if as intika says it takes an hour to set up the environment. Answers will often be up voted if the look good, and accusing someone of a serious breach of the rules so publically with so little evidence should not be rewarded with 125 rep IMO, **especially** when intika already knew the *correct* action to take and had taken it.

Comment: @TZHX i don't care about rep i just want justice... I want to keep believing on SO fairness. i am having a week holiday i putted all on SO because i believe this is worth it for other devs and because i found in the past many times answers here... it will be a pleasure to discuss with someone on a complicated question but not like that. i put a lot of effort on it and if you check my profile it's what i am doing 1 week ago only putting a lot of effort on complicated bounty questions when i can. then if you believe i don't deserve it, it's okay but certainly not a makeup copy past answer

Comment: Hah, even with all the downvotes you were proved right.  Congrats, and thanks.

Comment: @Will thankfully yes and i am thankful to the team for taking time to investigate

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We found a voting ring boosting up that answer and other posts. We've dealt with the matter, thanks for reporting!

Comment: Thanks for the investigation and the time you took for it. i am prouder to participate and give my free time to SO community because it's worth it, you have a good team behind it. newbie that spread negative reputation on Internet are just not fully aware of the site. THANK YOU FOR YOUR CONSIDERATION

Comment: @intika: in future: flagging the post is enough. Yes, it can sometimes take a little while for us to investigate and handle the issue. We handle thousands of flags each day, and for some work we have to rely on the Community Managers team, whom may not always be available either.

Comment: @Martjin ok understood :) thanks again

Answer (score 16):

Those are very strong accusations, you must have very good evidence to shame somebody in public like this.  You don't have enough, those 5 upvotes on his last post are not spaced close enough in time and are irregularly spaced.  That's not how serial voters work.

Bounty questions are normally only ever looked at when they move up to the first page.  At which point they get highly active.  Getting 5 votes for a "fancy post" then is not unusual.  And of course there is absolutely nothing wrong with a fancy post.  Nor is there anything wrong with bootstrapping an answer based on somebody else's post.  Collaborative answering is a key attribute of SO.

Do not engage in malicious downvoting either.  Vote for the post, not the person.

Instead of posting to meta, state your suspicions in a custom moderator flag.  They have access to information that's not readily available to you, giving them a better way to see sock puppet voting.  Don't throw another SO user in front a bus when you cannot be sure, you would not like this to happen to you either.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80096/discussion-on-answer-by-hans-passant-fraudulent-behavior).